# Are associated primes maximal elements of the annihilations?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, algebraic-number-theory

Given an $A$-module $M$. I know that maximal elements in the set
$$\{\mathrm{Ann}(m):0\ne m\in M\}$$
are associated primes. How about the opposite? Are associated primes maximal elements in that set?

Comment: No. As an example, take $A=M=k[x,y]/(x^2, xy)$. Then both $xA$ and $(x,y)A$ are associated primes, $xA$ is clearly not maximal in this set.

Comment: Seems like a full answer, not just a comment ;)

Comment: @Mohan That is what I was looking for. Thank you.